# adding multiple linearlayout inside a linearlayout programmatically crash

Tags: android, xml, layout

I was wanted to add a linearlayout which have an image and textview right after user pick a photo from local then display in a (parent)linearlayout. Adding first linearlayout have no problem but once I want to enter second linearlayout then the app crash.

**JAVA file**

```
public class newExpense extends Fragment {

ImageView addImage;
LinearLayout imageList;
final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_expense_copy, container, false);  

    addImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addImage);
    addImage.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveOnClickListener);

    imageList = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);

    return rootView;
}

ImageView.OnClickListener buttonSaveOnClickListener
= new ImageView.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select an option")
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               })
               .setItems(R.array.addImage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       if (which == 0) {
                           Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                           startActivityForResult(takePicture, RQS_LOADIMAGE);

                       } else {
                           Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                               android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                           startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , RQS_LOADIMAGE);
                       }
                   } 
               });
            builder.show();
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode){
        case RQS_LOADIMAGE:
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            LinearLayout injecterLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_list, imageList, false);

            ImageView img = (ImageView) injecterLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView txt = (TextView) injecterLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            img.setImageURI(imageUri);
            txt.setText(imageUri.getLastPathSegment().toString());
            imageList.addView(injecterLayout);

            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

}

**child layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minWidth="160dp"
    android:text="test" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageRemove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**parent layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amountLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/currency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Tap to enter amount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accountLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Paid From"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sat 02/03/2013" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noteLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Note"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locationLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photoLbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Photo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Log Cat**

```
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:733)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:562)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:340)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at com.example.expensesmanager.newExpense.onActivityResult(newExpense.java:92)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:161)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2987)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3034)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-03 23:14:05.676: E/AndroidRuntime(23792):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help with some modified code?? Appreciate the helps.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: As stated by @CommonsWare, use LogCat to determine where the problem is, and then post only the relevant code as well as your LogCat log.

Comment: When you read the stack trace, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare out of memory? I don't understand sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are out of memory, more specifically out of heap space. Your app is limited as to how much heap space it can use -- this will vary from as little as 16MB of space on old Android devices to perhaps as high as 64MB on new ones with high screen resolutions. Whatever it is, you used it all, perhaps on bitmaps.

You can [use MAT to find out where your heap space is being used](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Comment: I found out that adding image used up a lot of memory, but how to avoid this? i just need to add a preview image to the linearlayout.

Comment: @user2126362: "but how to avoid this?". Use fewer and/or smaller images at one time, doing what you can to free up the memory from the older images or recycling that memory (see `BitmapOptions` and `inBitmap`).

Comment: I've read that i need to decode and scale down the image but I don't know how. Can u help??

Comment: @user2126362: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I just want to ask that the "getresources()" is't getting the image?? Because now it can add but the image couldn't display.

img.setImageBitmap(
         decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView, 150, 150));